# Tensorflow: How buffer size from data.shuffle() influence data.cache()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I find when I set `train_ds = train_ds.cache(filename='...')`

`train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=int(training_size/10)).batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)`
During the first epoch of model fitting, what happened looks strange. [image: strange first epoch]

It seems that the model fitting ends before the feeding of the last 1/10 batches (this proportion is same as the proportion used in buffer size, I set this number in buffer size to save memory). Then the model fitting is restarted and the first epoch model fitting is finish.

I would like to ask 1) why this happens? 2) Is all my dataset successfully been cached rather than only the dataset for the first 90% batches is cached?

Comment: Note that: My dataset is simply set by using ```tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf_image_ds, tf_label_ds))```. And I never shuffle my datasets before cache().